# Base Classes constructor being hit without calling it?

Tags: c#, oop

Given the code:

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B(int i)
    {

    }
}
```

Then running the line:

```
  var x = new B(2);
```

I would never expect `A`'s constructor to get hit (unless I added `base()`) to the end of `B`'s constructor declaration.

Oddly it seems to be getting hit (and throwing the exception). Is this default behavior? This has caught me out as I fully never expected `A`'s constructor to be hit

Comment: This is default behavior.

Comment: If a parameterless base constructor exists and you don't specify the actual call to a specific construtor overload, it will always by called by default.

Comment: Consider what would happen to the instance if that didn't happen: some initialization might be skipped. That would be a Bad Thing.

Comment: Note that Java and C++ also work this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't include any `base(..)` or `this(..)`, it does the same thing as if you had `base()`. From the [C# spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645603%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

---

If an instance constructor has no constructor initializer, a constructor initializer of the form `base()` is implicitly provided. Thus, an instance constructor declaration of the form

```
C(...) {...}
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
C(...): base() {...}
```

---

You might've been looking to make `A` an [`abstract class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173150.aspx), so that you cannot directly create an instance of `A`.

```
public abstract class A
{
}

public class B : A
{
    public B(int i)
    {

    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    // A a = new A(); // doesn't compile
    A a = new B(2); // valid
}
```

Answer (score 1):

But within B class inherited by A class.so when you create on B instance ,automatically initiate the A instance as well.This is the default behavior in OOP concept.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behaviour. Constructors run in order from base class first to inherited class last. When you write base() then you can pass some value directly to base constructor

for eg

```
public class B : A
{
    public B(int i): base(i)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As your commentors have mentioned, this is the default C# behavior.  A constructor on each base class MUST be called.

If your rule is that ClassA should never be constructed (only child classes), declare ClassA as abstract

```
public abstract class A {}
```

With that syntax, it will be a compile-time error if you attempt to construct an A (but B will be ok), so you can remove the throw in A's constructor.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with the implicit call to the base constructor. If there is a constructor in the base class, it will be called even if the class is abstract.

Comment: @Groo I was inferring why the OP did not want the base constructor called -- the only code in his base constructor was a throw.  That implied that he doesn't want anyone constructing an instance of A.  If that's what he's going for, then he would be better off using an abstract class.

Comment: you're right, I thought that was just arbitrary code, but a `throw` really does imply something like that.

Answer (score 0):

That's expected: if you don't explicitly specify a different overload of a constructor, it will always be invoked by default. And even if you do specify a different overload to call, it will also propagate to its base class' constructor until it reaches the root `Object()` constructor.

Note that this also means that if you have a different constructor overload in a single class, instantiating the object through the overloaded constructor will **not** call the parameterless constructor of that same class, but instead the parameterless constructor of the base class (in this case, `Object()`):

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    public A(int i)
    {
        // this will not call the A(), but the base Object() constructor
    }
}

var a = new A(5); // no exception thrown
```